# Cloudfront Missing Key-Pair-Id Cookie Value with Cookies Present

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to debug an error with my Cloudfront setup signed cookies setup, where despite setting the correct three signed cookies to be able to access the private content (CloudFront-Key-Pair, CloudFront-Policy, CloudFront-Signature) and I'm curious what information needs to be carried over into the GET request for the CloudFront distribution file in order to verify these cookies. What I can currently understand about the situation is the following.

Error Message:

```
<Error>
<Code>MissingKey</Code>
<Message>
Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value
</Message>
</Error>
```

My Application (When I navigate around the website, the three cloudfront cookies are set within the Request and Response Cookies)

[image: cf cookies]
However, I noticed that these cookies are not present in the cloudfront GET request, but my other session cookies are present. Could this be a clue as to the problem I'm facing?

[image: cf file header]

Comment: Your cookies appear to be set on `b*****.com` but you're showing a request for `f*****.com`.  That isn't going to work.  They have to be set by the same domain where you are trying to use them ... otherwise the browser won't send them. Cookies don't cross domains.  What's going on with the two different domains?

Comment: Basically b****.com or `beta.site.com` is my application and where I am setting the cookies. f***.com or `files.site.com` is my alias record sub-domain which is pointed to my cloudfront distribution and that I was using to host the files that users access. In my CloudFront distribution I have both `beta.` and `files.` added to my Alternate Domain Names (CNAME). How should this actually be setup? Should I change the domain name on the cookies I set to `files.`? Is that possible to do despite the cookie being set on `beta.`?

Comment: You can't set cross-domain cookies (or cross-subdomain).  If browsers allowed that, it would be a huge potential security issue.  Cookies only work within, not across, the domain hierarchy.

Comment: Right, kind of rushed that comment without thinking about why it isn't possible to transfer across domains. As a result, would the correct decision be to create an alias record with `beta.site.com`? Is it possible to created an alias record pointing to the cloudfront distribution, but containing the same domain as my CNAME?