# CloudFront Debugging Missing Cookie Value

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I have had a difficult time determining what needs to be done with my CloudFront setup to be able to get my signed cookie setup working. I have carefully followed the steps and using a module with NodeJS to handle the cookie generation (https://github.com/jasonsims/aws-cloudfront-sign). With my current setup, cookies are being set for my application located at `beta.my-site.com`, but not appearing in either the request and response cookies when a link on my application accesses a file behind the cloudfront distribution (`files.my-site.com`). This has been frustrating because I feel like I have looked at everything and only have a few clues as to why my setup might not be working.

1) The first thing that stands out is that there isn't a domain name set for the cookies, this might be an issue as cookies should be able to persist through sub-domains as long as the domain remains the same.

2) Is there a way to test my cookies from `curl` to make sure that it doesn't have to do with the cookies I am setting? Unfortunately, due to the strictness of cloudfront and the need for cookies to have the same hostname as the cloudfront distribution configuration, it is not possible to test from `localhost`.

*Filenames and keys randomly generated and not real.*

**Cloudfront distribution configuration:**

```
Distribution Status: Deployed
Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): files.my-site.com, beta.my-site.com, *.my-site.com
SSL Certification: *.my-site.com (bjdsofjwpefsd4235)
Domain Name: uhr82459shfngbc.cloudfront.net
Custom SSL Client Support: SNI
Origin Domain Name: files-beta.s3.amazonaws.com
Restrict Bucket Access: Yes
Your Identities: access-identity-files-beta.s3.amazonaws.com
Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTPS Only
Allows HTTP Methods: GET, HEAD
Restrict Viewer Access: Yes
Trusted Signers: Self
```

**Route 53:**

```
beta.my-site.com CNAME server-beta.elasticbeanstalk.com
file.my-site.com A ALIAS uhr82459shfngbc.cloudfront.net
```

**Cookies set in my application (`beta.my-site.com`):**

[image]

**Cookies set when the file is accessed (`files.my-site.com`):**
[image]

Current code setup:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var moment = require('moment');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var cf = require('aws-cloudfront-sign');
var metaTags = require('./meta-routes');
var cfPK = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + /config/pk-UHANFBYH54248.pem));

var cfOptions = {
    keypairId: 'E5YGBKNfsdfds472',
    privateKeyString: cfPK
}

var signedCookies = cf.getSignedCookies('https://files.my-site.com/*', cfOptions);

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())

        for(var cookieId in signedCookies) {
            res.cookie(cookieId, signedCookies[cookieId]);
        }

        return next();
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Behavior setup:
[image]

Comment: I guess I left you hanging on the [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40010849/1695906) and nobody else came along.  You should probably delete one of them.  Without understanding more about your setup, it's hard to suggest the correct/ideal solution, but a potentially workable one is to put the entire application -- server and assets -- behind a *single* CloudFront distribution: 2 origins (files and app) and 2 (or more) cache behaviors, routing by path to the appropriate target, with cookies not required to access the app paths.  Then it "just works."   Helpful?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I agree that I should delete one of the questions and thank you for being nice enough to answer again. I'm not sure I follow this as origin files reference s3 buckets and not domain names. What would adding two do? I updated my question to include a screenshot of my origin setup for cloudfront.

Comment: You can add your app server (server-beta.elasticbeanstalk.com) as an additional origin (custom origin) to the distribution, and then you can route specific paths *through* CloudFront to your server by creating a new cache behavior with a specific path pattern... that way, those requests are on the "files" domain and the server can just set the cookies directly in the response... so files.example.com/app/* (for example) goes *through* CloudFront to your app server, while everything else at files.example.com/* goes through CloudFront to S3.

Comment: ...running your entire application (dynamic and static content) through a single CloudFront distribution by using multiple origins (bucket and server) simplifies things significantly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the help, the biggest issue was that I was not setting the `domain` attribute when I was setting the cloudfront cookies so I couldn't pass the them to the subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue has to do with the `N/A` value in the domain attribute of my Cloudfront Request Cookies. In order to pass the cookies from the parent domain to the subdomain, this attribute needs to have the value of the hostname.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. How did you add the hostname ?